# Excel - Variable Prefix

Tags: excel, formula, prefix

I am trying to create a prefix to any numerical amount entered into a cell. The key here is that the prefix needs to be able to changed by updating a number in one "entry" cell. I have a chart of accounts for a budget, the chart of accounts will be the same, however with each file (i.e. new budget) the property has a unique identifier that will need to be the prefix to the account numbers.

Example
Property Number: 700

Account 1: 3000
Account 2: 3100
Account 3: 3200

Lets say the property number (700) is in Cell A1, and the account numbers will be entered into cells A3, A4, A5, etc all the way down. When I enter "3000" in cell A3, I want "700-" to be displayed before it: 700-3000. Then if i change the amount in cell A1 (the property number) from 700 to 800 I want all of the account numbers to now have the "800-" before them... 800-3000

Looking for a non-VBA option if possible.

Any assistance would be greatly apprecated!

Comment: Not sure how to reference cell A1 with this method, but you can hardcode a number such as 700 and change it when necessary. First, highlight cells A3:A5, right click and go to Format Cells. On the Number tab go to Custom and where it says Type:, place this underneath: "700-"0;"700-"0

Comment: Thanks for your response, definitely a work around, but still would like the ability to have it automatically update the prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for Concatenate. In B3 enter

```
=CONCATENATE($A$1, "-",A3)
```

And copy down

Comment: Can alternatively be performed with &; as in: =$A$1&"-"&A3

Comment: Thank you, this will work and I did see this in the forums, however I will have to have the account code and property number referenced for it all to come together. Still trying to figure out how to just enter 3000 and have it come out "700-3000" with the 700 having the ability to change from cell A1

Comment: There isn't any non-VBA way to enter 3000 into A3 and have it automatically change in place to "700-3000" in such a way that it will then automatically update when A1 is changed. For that you would need =3000 to be automatically replaced by another formula. With VBA it would be fairly easy to do this. Are you sure that you want to avoid VBA?

Comment: Thanks John - I am just not that great with VBA so I was trying to stay away from it, but it looks like I will have to dive into it to get my desired result. Only one way to learn!

Answer (score 0):

A VBA Answer. In the code module for Sheet1 (or whatever sheet you want this for) try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 2 Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
            Target.Formula = "=Concatenate(A1,""-""," & Target.Value & ")"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If any number is entered in column A starting with the third row, that number is automatically converted to a formula which depends on cell A1